# Is it possible to parse multiple ini-files with PHP parse_ini_file function?

Tags: php

I wonder if it is possible to parse all ini files from a folder to one variable?
What I mean: there is a couple of ini-files in a folder

```
./whitelist/client1_whitelist.conf
./whitelist/client2_whitelist.conf
./whitelist/client3_whitelist.conf
```

The inner structure of files is identical.
Thanks.

I tried to load them all, like

```
foreach (glob("./whitelist/*.conf") as $filename)
{
    $whitelists = parse_ini_file($filename);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is that `parse_ini_file()` returns an array of settings.  This is assigned to the same variable each time, which removes the previous files values.

You could just use `array_merge` to add the new values each time into am overall list

```
$whitelists = [];
foreach (glob("./whitelist/*.conf") as $filename)
{
    $whitelists = array_merge($whitelists, parse_ini_file($filename));
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting as well that the order matters - later settings will overwrite earlier ones with the same key, and `glob` will default to listing files in alphabetical order. You can use this to your advantage with careful names like `000-defaults.ini`

Comment: @IMSoP, it's also a good point about using some form of naming conventions in your settings.  It would be easy to find that some random settings file is overwriting the multiple uses of the setting called 'user'.